# How to add a default action bar

Tags: android-actionbar

How to set **an Action bar** in the top of my screen when it doesn't appear in the preview in Android Studio? I'm using the API 21.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click Select Theme -> Light Holo -> Compact Menu
and that's it!